# Forge - The category 'rfaFile' in '$(rfaFile)' is unrecognized

Tags: api, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We are getting an error while executing a WorkItem in Forge's Design Automation API.
The error is this:

```
Error: The category 'rfaFile' in '$(rfaFile)' is unrecognized. Valid values are args, settings, appbundles, engine, engines.
```

And it happens right after the 'Start preparing script and command line parameters.' in the report.txt. We are not really sure why's this happening. It looks like the error is thrown in the activity. The activity looks like this:

```
function publishActivity() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "/api/forge/design_automation/activities",
          headers: {
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
            "Forge-Token": forgeToken
          },
          method: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            activity: {
              "id": "DeleteWallsActivity",
              "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rfaFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[TestAppId].path)\"" ],
              "parameters": {
                "rfaFile": {
                  "zip": false,
                  "ondemand": false,
                  "verb": "get",
                  "description": "Input Revit model",
                  "required": true,
                  "localName": "$(rfaFile)"
                },
                "result": {
                  "zip": false,
                  "ondemand": false,
                  "verb": "put",
                  "description": "Results",
                  "required": true,
                  "localName": "result.rfa"
                },
                "inputJson": {
                  "verb": "get",
                  "description": "input json",
                  "localName": "params.json",
                  "ondemand": false,
                  "required": false,
                  "zip": false
                }                
              },
              "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2021",
              "appbundles": [ "petar3db.TestAppId+test" ],
              "description": "Deletes walls from Revit file."              
            }
          })
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log("Activity created");
          bundleUploadData = data["uploadParameters"];
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          console.log("Failed to create activity", jqXHR.responseJSON);
          console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
        });
      }
```

and it looks like the `"localName": "$(rfaFile)"` is causing the trouble.
Let's take a look at our WorkItem code which we execute via websockets:

```
{
 "headers": {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer <token here>"
 },
 "action": "post-workitem",
 "data": {
    "activityId": "petar3db.DeleteWallsActivity+test",
    "arguments": {
        "rfaFile": {"url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/da992c60-a3d7-469d-8c3e-d0f089e2e509?region=US", "pathInZip": "emptyfam.rfa"},
        "result": {"verb": "put", "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b78151c1-93aa-495f-96c8-183bca26e071?region=US"},
        "inputJson": {"localName": "params.json", "url": "the url to the file"}
    }
 }
}
```

the really strange part is that this process worked just fine and started throwing this error when we added `"inputJson"` into the activity and workItem. (We want to send some JSON data to the AppBundle with the WorkItem)
What can be the issue? Are missing something?

Comment: Is there a typo in your post or are these the exact values? Looks like you have a parameter in the activity called `rfaFile` but the workitem argument is `rvtFile`. Although, if that is the case we should do a better job with reporting this error to you.

Comment: @RahulBhobe yes, it was a typo, sorry.. It's not working with rfaFile either.

Comment: Ok! Do you have the same error? Any specific reason you want to zip the rfa file?

Comment: @RahulBhobe nope, after implementing what Emma Zhu suggested, we don't have the same error anymore. Unfortunately, we have a new one: Document error: The "Document doc = data.RevitDoc;" line is returning null in the addin code, so I can't even get to the point to call LoadFamily. There is nothing really special about the zip file, but if I'm right, that is not the issue at all, as the AppBundle can work with .zip files?

Comment: Did you want to load this family into another document or just open it? If you want to load it, then what document do you want to load it in :-)? Taking away the `/i ` argument from command line, makes DA not open any document and hence you get a null pointer. If you want to "open" the family document, then do one of these 2 options - `a)` add the `/i` argument back to your command line and do not zip the family file when sending it to DA. DA will open if for you. Or `b)` Follow Emma's answer and use [OpenDocumentFile](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/11420983-6d0d-0022-e24c-2361c4e42fba.htm)

Comment: Oh I forgot to use OpenDocumentFile... It works now, thank you so much @RahulBhobe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for `"localName": "$(rfaFile)"`, to be noted that if the local name is defined like this, Design Automation will come up a valid name for this argument by its own logic. If you want to fully control the input file, such as accessing it in the addin(Appbundles)'s code, it is recommended to define a "real" localName instead, e.g. `"localName": "input.rfa"`

In your case above, you may need to:

- Remove `/i \"$(args[rfaFile].path)\"` from `commandLine` in the `Activity`
- Define `"localName": "inputRFA"`, so the input will be downloaded, **unzipped** as a folder named as `inputRFA`. `emptyfam.rfa` should be under this folder.
- Call OpenDocumentFile in the addin to open a Revit file, get `document`
- Call `document.LoadFamily(".\inputRFA\emptyfam.rfa", out family);` in the adding to open/load rfa file. See [this Revit API](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/67277d5a-0ddf-b617-c9c9-911ecb928af9.htm)

Comment: Thank you Emma. I set up everything just like you described, but now I have a Document error: The "Document doc = data.RevitDoc;" line is returning null in the addin code, so I can't even get to the point to call LoadFamily. I guess I should change here something as well?

Comment: I fixed the error from the comment above, One should use OpenDocumentFile in the Addin code as Rahul Bhobe suggested!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in `parameter` name in `activity` with the `argument` name in `workitem`. Correct way to post the `workitem` should be:

```json
{
 "headers": {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer <token here>"
 },
 "action": "post-workitem",
 "data": {
    "activityId": "petar3db.DeleteWallsActivity+test",
    "arguments": {
        "rfaFile": {"url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/da992c60-a3d7-469d-8c3e-d0f089e2e509?region=US", "pathInZip": "emptyfam.rfa"},
        "result": {"verb": "put", "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b78151c1-93aa-495f-96c8-183bca26e071?region=US"},
        "inputJson": {"localName": "params.json", "url": "the url to the file"}
    }
 }
}
```

Change the `argument` field `rvtFile` to `rfaFile`.

Comment: You are right, it was a typo.. However, it's not working with rfaFile either. I fixed the typo in the question.